# Convert private key from der to pem

Tags: openssl

I have a private and public key in der format which i'm trying to convert into .pem format in order to extract the text between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.I've already achieved that for the public key, but for the private key i get the following error.

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -in priv.der
```

but i get an error `8536` with the private key with the message `unable to load certificate`.Why is that?
[image]

Comment: Right Stack Exchange for this is http://serverfault.com .
This issue seems a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/786328/error-in-converting-crt-certificate-to-pem

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `-inform DER` command line option:

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -inform DER -in private.der
```

Comment: Thanks, but i've already tried that too.I still get an error saying "unable to load Private Key"